# Why can't I read data from Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase and I don't understand why I'm not able to get the data in tMAX and same variables(tMAX always returns as 0.0 and same as 0). I tried many things that I found but with all of them I get the same result when debugging.
What am I doing wrong? 
Is this the right way to read from the database? Have I missed something?

Strings.java -here is where I do the reading

```
public class Settings {
    double tMAX;
    int NumNodes;
    int LastNode;
    int Source;
    int same;

    DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabase;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseInstance;
    String userID;
    public Settings()  {
        mFirebaseInstance=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        userID= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        mFirebaseDatabase=mFirebaseInstance.getReference().child("user").child(userID).child("1");
        mFirebaseDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot1: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(snapshot != null){
                        User user = snapshot1.getValue(User.class);
                        if(user != null){
                            tMAX = user.getDuration();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e("Settings", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });

        NumNodes=31;

        mFirebaseDatabase.child("2").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot1: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(snapshot != null){
                        User2 user = snapshot1.getValue(User2.class);
                        if(user != null){
                            same=user.getSourceDestination().get(0);
                            if(same==1){
                                NumNodes+=1;
                                Source=0;
                                LastNode=0;
                            }
                            else{
                                NumNodes+=2;
                                Source=0;
                                LastNode=32;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.e("Settings", "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
            }
        });

    }
}
```

And this is how my database looks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/83q0G.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Change the following:

```
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot1: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(snapshot != null){
                        User user = snapshot1.getValue(User.class);
                        if(user != null){
                            tMAX = user.getDuration();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

into this:

```
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.exists()){
                        User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                        tMAX      = user.getDuration();
                    }
                }
```

First, you need to use the `exists()` method to check if there is data at that location. Second, you shouldn't iterate inside the snapshot since you are using a POJO class. When you are iterating you are retrieving data of type `String` and not type `User`.

Comment: That's how I was doing it before, I get the same result

Comment: then do this: `@Override
            public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.exists()){
                        Double duration = Double.parseDouble(snapshot.child("duration").getValue(String.class));
                    }
                }`

Comment: And I should add tMAX=duration, or how can I get the value from duration?

Comment: yes add `tMAX = duration` or just do `tMAX = Double.parseDouble(snapshot.child("duration").getValue(String.class));`

Comment: what are ur database rules?

Comment: they are both on true

Comment: Do `@Override public void onDataChange(@NotNull DataSnapshot snapshot) { if(snapshot.exists()){ Double duration = snapshot.child("duration").getValue(Double.class); String date = snapshot.child("date").getValue(String.class);} }`

Comment: And tell me if u get the date

Comment: The date is null

Comment: What does the snapshot contain when u debug?

Comment: When I place the Breakpoint inside of the onDataChange function I can see that snapshot grabs the values, but when I place the Breakpoint in the Settings() method  it skips over the reading and gives tMAX the value 0.0

Comment: where are u calling `Settings()`? Also remove the second valueeventlistener and test again

Comment: I am calling it in this method https://imgur.com/a/a24lpyl that I am calling in an onClick method https://imgur.com/a/GKeajJR